# Xamarin.Forms how to change the navigation back button to an image?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I am building an app in Visual studio with crossed platform in Xamarin.Forms.
I have been trying to change the back arrow button in the navigation UI to an image in stead of the arrow, but I haven't found any good examples.
Is there anyone here who can help me?

Comment: Which platform do you want to change it on? Android?

Answer (score 0):

Back arrow button in navigation bar is default feature. I think it can't be changed. If you want to change it then you should use a custom navigation bar.

Comment: Please include an example and/or references from linked sources that offers a solution for the question.